# Tool tip not working using jquery on slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-tooltip

I've just started working on jquery tooltip. But, its not firing. I've a slider and on the slider there is a circle on it. Whenever I click on the circle to the next point, it should show me the tool tip with some message. Here is my code

```
var tooltip = $('#ncbtooltip');
    tooltip.hide();
    var slider = $(".slider-horizontal");
    slider.slider().find(".tooltip-inner").append(tooltip).click(function () {
        //Not working 
        $("#tooltip1 .tooltip-inner .spnNCBMessage").text("Hey");
        tooltip.show()
    }, function () {
        tooltip.hide()
    })
```

### HTML

```
<div id="ncbtooltip" class="tooltip fade top in tooltip-light">
   <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
   <div class="tooltip-inner"><b>Awesome!</b> You're now eligible for NCB of <span  class="spnNCBMessage"></span>%</div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: See example [here...](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: where do you put on the slider - need some more code to play with it.

Comment: Sorry. I'll update the details.